# Difference between std::end(myVector) and myVector.end()

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers

I've noticed there are 2 ways to get the end iterator of a vector (or other container class):

```
std::end(myVector)
```

and

```
myVector.end()
```

The same goes for various other container iterator functions, `begin`, `cend`, `cbegin`, `rend`, `rbegin`, `crend`, `crbegin`, `find`, etc.  What I'm wondering is if there's any functional difference between these?  And if not, is there some historical reason to have both of them?

(Apologies if this is a duplicate, I've searched all over, and found plenty of sources for one or the other of these methods, but none that mentions both or compares the two.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a historical reason: before C++11, only the member function versions existed. C++11 added the non-members, which also work for plain C-style arrays, so can be considered to be more general.

```
int a[] = {3, 1, 5, 67, 28, -12};
std::sort(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
```

When applied to standard library containers, the effect of `std::begin` and `std::end` is to call the container's `begin()` and `end()` member functions, so there is no functional difference.

C++14 added `std::cbegin`, `std::cend`, `std::rbegin`, `std::rend`, `std::crbegin` and `std::crend`, with similar behaviour.

Comment: So the only difference is the new method also works on arrays?  Okay.  Useful, I guess - I may have to ask the person who wrote this code why we're using it on `vector`s and just making the code needlessly more verbose, but I guess that answers my question.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I guess it is a matter of choice, but I prefer using non-member functions if possible. BTW if the parameter is a standard library container, the `std::` can be omitted, and `begin(v)` isn't much more verbose than `v.begin()`.

Comment: Yes, though potentially dangerous in this case - Much of our codebase is shared by many teams in different parts of the world, some of whom are still running C++0x for legacy reasons.  I don't expect this particular part of the code to cause problems, but there've been conflicts in the past over that.  (We have to mark certain classes as "No C++11 allowed" so that it doesn't break other teams' builds...)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: note that although `std::begin`, `std::end` (etc.) were only added to the standard in C++11 (and 14), they can be implemented using only features available in C++98, so if you want to use free functions and retain compatibility with older compilers, that's entirely possible.

Comment: I like v1.insert(begin(v2), end(v2)); more than v1.insert(v2.begin(), v2.end()). It seems cleaner and leverages ADL to drop "std::" prefix. It's shorter by 2 characters as well :) Of course, due to ADL, it doesn't work with raw arrays. You'd have to provide the std:: prefix then.

Taking advantage of ADL is cool and not many people use that, e.g.: find(begin(v), end(v), value); is much cleaner without "std::"